# Use jBuilder template to make a Hash

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

Is there a way to get jBuilder to generate a Hash from a template instead of a string?

`render(template: "foo", formats: :json)` will return stringified JSON.

I can of course parse the stringified JSON, though it's sub-optimal to render JSON as a string and then parse it again. My assumption is that the JSON does exist as a Hash at some point before being turned into a string.

For example, given a jBuilder template like this:

```
json.foo "bar"
```

I would like to know how to get jBuilder to generate `{foo: "bar"}` instead of `"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"`

Comment: Why are you using jBuilder? Have you tried parsing it and benchmarking to see if the penalty is as bad as you think? Can you pass jBuilder a hash object? What does your template look like? What do you mean exactly as render? What makes you think the JSON is a hash at some point? If so can you just pass it to a template directly? And finally: have you tried `JSON.parse(my_json)` to see if it is slow?

Comment: @Beartech jBuilder is maintained by Rails, so it's a pseudo-default. I don't know that it exists as a Hash at some point, but I do assume that jBuilder isn't creating the JSON progressively as it goes. It's an assumption, as I stated. I would like to know the answer to the question regardless of what the template looks like or how long it actually takes. I'll change my wording to remove the word "render".

Comment: I guess the point of all of my questions is; without seeing and example of what you actually want to happen, I don't see a way to answer your question without even a minimal example of expected output. i.e. what is your use case? Hopefully a jBuilder expert sees it. Maybe post to their Github page?

Comment: @Beartech Alright, toy example added

Comment: Ok simple enough. But the thing is you are generating JSON. JSON is by definition a structured string. I meant how are you CONSUMING the output from jBuilder? You are asking it to generate JSON. That is what is going to do. Is it the fact that the keys are expressed as strings like "foo": that is bothering you? Please forgive my confusion but it's like you're asking "how do I get paper shredder to output un-shredded paper?" So I am still confused.

Comment: Also if you parse JSON with `JSON.parse(foo)` you are going to get  `{"foo"=>"bar"}` . If you wanted symbols you'd have to do `JSON.parse(foo).symbolize_keys` to get them back into symbols.

Comment: jBuilder returns stringified JSON. I want parsed JSON. But presumably jBuilder started off with a Ruby Hash object that it stringified to create the stringified JSON. I know that it can use multiple JSON stringification libraries such as OJ. So if its JSON string generation is modular like that, it again implies that the data exists in a non-string format before it is turned into a string. It also just makes sense. Progressively generating the JSON string would be cool, but I feel that it's unlikely.

I don't care about symbols vs strings, either is fine.